# Simultaneous iteration over several lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want to use `zip` and `map` to simultaneously iterate over 3 lists:

```
l0 = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2 = [2,3,4,5,6,7]

result = map(lambda x, y, z: x+y+z, zip(l0, l1, l2))

print(tuple(result))
```

but it returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythontest.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(tuple(result))
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Why u have to use `zip` here? why not `list(map(lambda x, y, z: x+y+z, l0, l1, l2))`? Just curious..

Comment: @YatishKadam I just tested it. It won't throw an error.

Comment: @Mr_U4913 yes i deleted the comment.. i tested too .. got the error first time cause of a different issue.. my bad

Comment: @Mr_U4913 i did a bit of research on this.. Zip is basically more flexible.. Lets say we have l0 which is list.. while l1 is a string.. zip would work in such a case.. while just using it straight forward adding wont..

Comment: another useful thing to note is that.. when you use zip the result is just a tuple which holds the value.. the lambda will give an error only when you try to print it out the result.. 
when you directly try to add it .. it will immediately throw an error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is you are using the wrong variables... The zip returns a single element which contains the individual values.. 
So you need to access that by using the indices.

```
l0 = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2 = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1]+x[2], zip(l0, l1, l2))
Out[23]: <map at 0x7fa48232f710>
result = map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1]+x[2], zip(l0, l1, l2))

print(tuple(result))
(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13)
```

Comment: Do I need to have `list(map(...))`?

Comment: not really.. youll get the values how ever you are doing it.. you just need the lambda to get the correct variable..

Answer (score 2):

You could use only one argument in your `lambda` function, since `zip` creates tuples of 3 elements, and then apply the `sum` function:

```
result = map(lambda elem: sum(elem), zip(l0, l1, l2))
```

Comment: This makes the `lambda` completely superfluous though. You can, and should, simplify further to just `map(sum, zip(l0, l1, l2))`.